# How to change the group text color of objectlistview?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm looking to change the group text color in an objectlistview control.

[image]

I've read what documentation I've been able to find including the tutorials posted

here: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html,

here: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html,

and hear: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html.

All other attempts to search for a solution have come up empty. The objectlistview control has a `GroupWithItemCountFormat` property which (according to the help text) contains both `get{}` and `set{}` methods and purports to regulate the group label format when a group is empty or contains more than one item. Although this seems promising, I've been unable to manipulate the value of that property in any meaningful way, and, even if I could, I'm not so sure the property controls what I'm after. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# - Change color of groups in ObjectListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700669/c-sharp-change-color-of-groups-in-objectlistview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the creator of the ObjectListView component you can't control how the group headers will be rendered. I'm attaching the relevant questions/answers that I have found about this:

- [c# - Change color of groups in ObjectListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700669/c-sharp-change-color-of-groups-in-objectlistview)
- https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812922/thread/9b2498d6/